# Timer job move to different farm

Tags: custom-timer-job

I have created timer job as per the article [How to Create Timer Job in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/).

It is running fine in site collection in dev environment.

- What are the steps to move it from dev to different environment? 
  I was going to save site collection as a template and restore it in target farm,
- what about the timer job? What are the steps to move it to diferent environment?
- In Event receiver, there is a Guid. This is the Site or list Guid?

Edit:
I have list in the site collection with custom form. Timer job is created to daily check the list and send reminders etc.
Need to move both to the different environment.
So for site collection it will be: save as a template etc.
What are steps to move timer job definition?

Comment: Why you tried to restore all site collection ? is it require ? or you only need to move timer job to another environment ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "moving the timer job". Do you want to move the definition or you are trying to move the running instances? Sorry to have to ask, but your notice " I was going to save site collection as a template and restore it in target farm" seems to indicate that you want to migrate the site collection too, and that made me wonder

Answer (score 0):

Timer Jobs resides inside an assembly and it gets executed by SharePoint Timer Windows service.

To move timer job you need to create a WSP solution in Visual Studio. In that solution add a Feature and use the Feature Activated event to install the timer job.

Comment: Whata about the GUID in the Event receiver section? Should it be site collection or list that timer is targeting? code that has GUID in it:      namespace TimerJob.Features.TimerJobFeature
{
    [Guid("26823a41-8eb4-4103-bab9-35554f567c8a")]
    public class TimerJobFeatureEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver{